# vim: How to change closed folders' view?

Tags: linux, vim

I'm using `vim` folding. The closed folder looks like this:

```
+-- 7 lines: first_folder() ---------------------------------
```

Can I configure the view of the closed folders in vim? For example remove the num of lines or maybe change folder's name (`first_folder`) color?
Thank you for your help.